# How to sort lists present in backbone model?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a backbone model with the following defination

```
var ABCModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return {
            Id: -1,
            Name: "",
            SomeCollectionABC: "",
            SomeCollectionXYZ: ""
        };
    }
});
```

Now the values in SomeCollectionABC is of the following format :

```
[
    Object { Id=28, Day="MON", Score=0, more...},
    Object { Id=25, Day="TUE", Score=7, more...},
    Object { Id=25, Day="MON", Score=7, more...},
    Object { Id=25, Day="WED", Score=7, more...},
]
```

to this model I add and remove objects on the fly, I want to be able to sort this list with different properties, say sometime I want to sort with 'Id', sometime sort with 'Day'.

How do I do it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use underscore.js's `_.sortBy` function.

```
_.sortBy(ABCModel.get('SomeCollectionXYZ'), function(obj) {
    // your sorting logic
});
```

Or something like:

```
 var ABCModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
 // your existing code ...

 sortXYZ:function(param) {
   var result = _.sortBy(this.get('SomeCollectionXYZ'), 
     function(obj) { 
       return obj[param];
      });
   return result; // or this.set({SomeCollectionXYZ:result});
  }
});

ABCModel.sortXYZ('Day'); // or ABCModel.sortXYZ('Id');
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a regular collection/array, then use underscore as the other answer suggests. If it is a Backbone Collection then you can make use of the `comparator` property

```
var SomeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    comparator: function(model){
         return model.get('someProperty');
     }
}
```

and then it should keep itself in a sorted order. If you need to you can also call

```
SomeCollection.sort();
```